# Resizing CALayers in AVSynchronizedLayer while playbacking video composition

Tags: ios, avfoundation, calayer

I have created a video composition with multiple CALayers. 
When I try to playback this composition, it works fine. And, I have been trying to resize AVPlayerLayer and its synchronizedlayer to play composition in full screen, avplayelayer and synchronizedlayer are getting resized but not animated sublayers in synchronizedlayer.

How can I resize all layers in video composition without affecting animations?

Answer (score 1):

You need to resize the main sublayer of AVSynchronizedLayer.  From Class Reference for AVSynchronizedLayer:

> A synchronized layer is similar to a CATransformLayer object in that
>   it doesn't display anything itself, it just confers state upon its
>   layer subtree. AVSynchronizedLayer confers its timing state,
>   synchronizing the timing of layers in its subtree with that of a
>   player item